# How do I create an inverse-distance weighted attribute mean map?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

An attribute-weighted heatmap applies inverse distance weighting to each point in a set proximity and adds them all up. I am searching for a tool in QGIS or another software that allows me to do the same thing using mean values.

Ex: in an area on a map with 2 nearby data points, one is 4 units away with value 10, the other is 1 unit away with value 40, the point will have value of (4/5)*40+(1/5)*10=32+2=34. This is a weighted average based on point distance, which would make it easier to interpret for my purposes.

I do not want to use an interpolation grid, and I do not want to use a mean grid since I want the result to be a geographically-moving average (ie: should visually look like a heatmap and not a grid).